# Information from one fragment is not sending to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a main Activity which contains two Fragments (Each in it's own activity) as ActionTabListener

[image]

Everytime I hit the **Calculate** button I want the information to append on top of what's already under **Display Result** activity textbox and not overwrite. I tried SharedPreference, but it only works to `setText()` but `.append()` doesn't work.

The TextBox is initialized under the **Display Trip** as

> private EditText showLog;

Should I change it to `private`?

How do I transfer information between the two activities without losing them within the duration of the application in the memory?

Comment: Create a class that holds this information and pass an instance of it as you wish.

Comment: Would it be possible to show an example?

Comment: I can show how to pass an instance between two other objects, but I don't have time to make a full Fragment example. Anyway, Fragments are instances, so the concept is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 Practice2 newFragment = new Practice2();

                bundle.putString("id", "Information");
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(R.id.llhome, newFragment);

                // Commit the transaction
                transaction.commit();
```

and replace the current version of display result with it's self but with the information
and if you want you can attach multiple bundles for each string  you want to show.

Comment: Is that going in the Display Result activity or the Current Trip activity? I am taking one string which has multiple variables and sending it to Display Result activity.

Comment: @SiKni8 If you set it to replace the Display Result Fragment Activity (set Practice2 to the name of the Display Result Activity class) it should replace that screen and not your current one

Comment: Thanks. One issue I have is switching between the tab resets my textboxes and radio selects. How do I prevent that?

Comment: @SiKni8 How are your tabs set up?

Comment: Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956973/saving-instance-to-avoid-losing-data-switching-between-tab for the question, do if you answer, you can get credit.